An addition to the beginning of a word is Prefix and an addition to the end is a Suffix

An addition to the beginning of a word is Prefix and an addition to the end is a
Suffix.

I found this above sentence and wonder why there is no 'a' in front of the word 'Prefix' compared with 'a' which is in front of the word 'Suffix'.

There's are three errors in the example sentence.  It should be "a prefix" and "a suffix", and neither should have capitals as these are just common nouns, not proper nouns.

Here's a link to the source, which continues with k‡ãi cÖ_‡g hv †hvM nq, Zv‡K e‡j Prefix (DcmM©)|
k‡ãi †k‡l hv †hvM nq, Zv‡K e‡j Suffix (cÖZ¨q)|. Certainly doesn't look as if it's from native Anglophones.

@FumbleFingers - That's what you get if you copy and paste Bengali script. Gomadeng, that document is very bad quality. The English is full of errors.

@MichaelHarvey: Indeed. It hardly inspires confidence to read that At the end of this lesson you will be able to ... strengthen your skill of English language.

The text is faulty. They each need an indefinite article. Neither of those words should be capitalized, either.
